# Avoid jquery datatables changing pagination on site reload

Tags: jquery, datatables

For big tables I use jquery data tables. For example The pagination is on page 4 and with a reload of the site (because of a sent form) the pagination jumps automatically to the first pagination site.

Is there a possibility to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**`stateSave`**](http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html) option. Basic usage (dataTables **1.10.x**) :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    stateSave: true
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/cayb99cq/**

Select a page, then right click in the frame where the datatable is (the lower right frame) and select "reload frame".

Answer (score 0):

You can post the pagination value (ie page number or limit an offset) with the form itself and retrieve data for the data table for that pagination value.

OR

Submit form using AJAX (ie dynamic) and reload only that div

Comment: How do I get the pagination number from jquery datatables?

Comment: I solved this topic by reading the API carefully. The option "bStateSave": true keeps the current pagination number

Comment: Post offset with form submit and while reterving data from db use the posted offset as offset, limit

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if your doign a draw or invalidate jsut pass false and the pagination will remain IE:

table.cell( this ).invalidate().draw(false);